# AngularJS: Apply search filter only to first child of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-filter

I have the MVP plunkr [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jsd9Fb7YmVNpXhnELBx5?p=preview)

I m trying to apply the search function only to the activePlayers list and not on all 3 lists.

i tried something like

`<li ng-repeat="item in list | filter: {activePlayers: searchText}"`

But that did not worked out too well.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **filter: listName== 'activePlayers'? searchText : ''**

It will work.

Comment: That worked like a charm. 
`searchText : ' ' "  ` 

just had to add quotes for empty condition

Thanks a ton